# SonarQube webservice API for delta load?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I see that Sonarqube provides an Webservice API to get all issues and I will load this data in to a database for analysis. Then, I wish to have my reporting database in sync with the changes happening in the system. Do we have a Webservice API that captures change data?

Overall, I want reporting DB to be in sync with the system.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to expand on the meaning of "modified data as a delta load"?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam - Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createdAfter` parameter of the [issues search web service](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues/search) will get you new issues, but there's no analogous `updatedAfter` parameter. Note that by only looking at added issues, you'll overlook issues that are closed in a new analysis.

Comment: Lets assume, there are 10 issues(2-assigned, 8-closed) in the system and I have extracted them and loaded into my reporting database. Now, after couple of days these 2 issues status changes to resolved in the system. Is it possible to update the status in my reporting DB by referring any webservice API?